# jquery mobil basic plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I like to build a popup, but it doesn't work. I had took a example from the jquery mobile documentation.
http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> 
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text-html" ; charset=UTF-8" />
>       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
>       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />      
>       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
>       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
>       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
>
>     </head> 
>     <body>
>       <div data-role="page">
>           <div data-role="header">
>               <h1>Basic plugin</h1>
>           </div>
>           <div data-role="content">
>
>           <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>
>           <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
>               This is a completely basic popup, no options set.
>           </div>
>           </div>
>       </div>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I'd changed the version to 1.3.2, unfortunately it's not changed the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a later version of jQuery Mobile, as popups were only introduced in v1.2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text-html" ; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Basic plugin</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">

            <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
                This is a completely basic popup, no options set.
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**[Working jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/J4UbU/)**

Comment: I'll update my answer to use 1.3.2, since that's the latest version.  I'll also include a working jsfiddle since you said you can't get it working.